# Can I use the vue-google-autocomplete package with Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, google-places-api

I used the vue-google-autocomplete package (https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete) in a Laravel 9 Vue 2 project. Will this work in Laravel 10 Vue 3 project. The reason I am asking this is because it says on the project repo page: "A Vue.js (2.x) autosuggest component for the Google Maps Places API."

If this package does not work in Vue 3, an suggestion for an alternative package that I can use.

Comment: https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete/issues/177

Comment: I tried the same code that I used in the Vue 2 application in Vue 3, and it worked! Thanks @yoduh